# Stochastic differential equation with callback in Julia

Tags: callback, julia, differentialequations.jl

I'm trying to solve a diffusion problem with reflecting boundaries, using various SDE integrators from `DifferentialEquations.jl`. I thought I could use the `FunctionCallingCallback` to handle the boundaries, by reflecting the solution about the domain boundaries after every integrator step.

This is my code

```
using DifferentialEquations

K0 = 1e-3
K1 = 5e-3 
alpha = 0.5

K(z)    = K0 + z*K1*exp(-z*alpha)
dKdz(z) = K1*exp(-alpha*z) - K1*alpha*z*exp(-alpha*z)

a(z,p,t) = dKdz(z)
b(z,p,t) = sqrt(2*K(z))

dt = 0.1
tspan = (0.0,1.0)

z0 = 1.0

prob  = SDEProblem(a,b,z0,tspan)

function reflect(z, p, t, integrator)
    bottom = 2.0
    if z < 0
        # Reflect from surface
        z = -z
    elseif z > bottom
        # Reflect from bottom
        z = 2*bottom - z
    end
    return z
end

cb = FunctionCallingCallback(reflect;
                 func_everystep = true,
                 func_start = true,
                 tdir=1)

sol = solve(prob, EM(), dt = dt, callback = cb)
```

**Edit:** After solving my initial problem thanks to the comment by Chris Rackauckas, I modified my reflect function. Now the code runs, but the solution contains negative values, which should have been prevented by reflection about 0 after every step.

Any ideas as to what's going wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Note by the way that the `FunctionCallingCallback` example found [here](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/features/callback_library.html#FunctionCallingCallback-1) contains two different function signatures for the callback function, but I get the same problem with both. It's also not clear to me if the callback should modify the value of `z` in place, or return the new value.

**Edit 2:**
Based on Chris Rackauckas' answer, and looking at [this example](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/features/callback_functions.html#ContinuousCallback-Examples-1), I've modified by reflect function thus:

```
function reflect(z, t, integrator)
    bottom = 2.0
    if integrator.u < 0
        # Reflect from surface
        integrator.u = -integrator.u
    elseif integrator.u > bottom
        # Reflect from bottom
        integrator.u = 2*bottom - integrator.u
    end
    # Not sure if the return statement is required
    return integrator.u
end
```

Running this with initial condition `z0 = -0.1` produces the following output:

```
retcode: Success
Interpolation: 1st order linear
t: 11-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0                
 0.1                
 0.2                
 0.30000000000000004
 0.4                
 0.5                
 0.6                
 0.7                
 0.7999999999999999 
 0.8999999999999999 
 1.0                
u: 11-element Array{Float64,1}:
 -0.1                 
 -0.08855333388147717 
  0.09862543518953905 
  0.09412012313587219 
  0.11409372573454478 
  0.10316400521980074 
  0.06491042188420941 
  0.045042097789392624
  0.040565317051189105
  0.06787136817395374 
  0.055880083559589955
```

It seems to me that what's happening here is:

1. The first output value is just `z0`. I expected the reflection to be applied first, given that I set `func_start = true`.
2. The second value also being negative indicates two things:

   1. The callback was not called prior to the first integrator call.
   2. The callback was not called prior to storing the output after the first integrator call.

I would have expected all the values in the output to be positive (i.e., have the callback applied to them before storing the output). Am I doing something wrong, or should I simply adjust my expectations?

Comment: `z[z .< 0.0]` is going to fail with a BoundsError because you defined `z` as a Float64, not an array.

Comment: Great, thanks! I was translating a python code where z was an array, but it seems in Julia it's easier to use the MonteCarloProblem approach, so I settled on that but forgot to change the reflect function. I still can't get it to work as I want though (see edits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FunctionCallingCallback` is a function `(u,t,integrator)`, so I'm not sure how your code didn't error for you. It should be:

```
using DifferentialEquations

K0 = 1e-3
K1 = 5e-3
alpha = 0.5

K(z)    = K0 + z*K1*exp(-z*alpha)
dKdz(z) = K1*exp(-alpha*z) - K1*alpha*z*exp(-alpha*z)

a(z,p,t) = dKdz(z)
b(z,p,t) = sqrt(2*K(z))

dt = 0.1
tspan = (0.0,1.0)

z0 = 1.0

prob  = SDEProblem(a,b,z0,tspan)

function reflect(z, t, integrator)
    bottom = 2.0
    if z < 0
        # Reflect from surface
        z = -z
    elseif z > bottom
        # Reflect from bottom
        z = 2*bottom - z
    end
    return z
end

cb = FunctionCallingCallback(reflect;
                 func_everystep = true,
                 func_start = true,
                 tdir=1)

sol = solve(prob, EM(), dt = dt, callback = cb)
```

### Edit

You don't want the function calling callback. Just use the normal callback:

```
using DifferentialEquations

K0 = 1e-3
K1 = 5e-3
alpha = 0.5

K(z)    = K0 + z*K1*exp(-z*alpha)
dKdz(z) = K1*exp(-alpha*z) - K1*alpha*z*exp(-alpha*z)

a(z,p,t) = dKdz(z)
b(z,p,t) = sqrt(2*K(z))

dt = 0.1
tspan = (0.0,1.0)

z0 = 1.0

prob  = SDEProblem(a,b,z0,tspan)

condition(u,t,integrator) = true
function affect!(integrator)
    bottom = 2.0
    if integrator.u < 0
        # Reflect from surface
        integrator.u = -integrator.u
    elseif integrator.u > bottom
        # Reflect from bottom
        integrator.u = 2*bottom - integrator.u
    end
end

cb = DiscreteCallback(condition,affect!;save_positions=(false,false))

sol = solve(prob, EM(), dt = dt, callback = cb)
```

Comment: Ok. The two function signatures in the example linked in my post are `func(u,p,t,integrator)` and `func(t,u,integrator)`, so I guess neither of those are correct. In any case, this still doesn't work for me. When I run this exact code, but with z0 = -0.1, I get only negative values of z (randomly varying around -0.1) in the solution. I found another example that indicates I need to modify `integrator.u` instead of `z`, though. Getting increasingly close to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Updated original post.

Comment: The new one is the one you want.

Comment: This still doesn't quite do what I expected. With this code, I get an output vector of 21 elements instead of 11, where every time point except 0.0 is repeated. And the two first solution values are still negative when running with `z0 = -0.1`, which indicates that the callback isn't applied prior to the first integrator call (I can live with that, though). For all the repeated outputs (i.e., all except t = 0.0), the first seems to be the output from the integrator, while the second has the callback applied to it, e.g., at t = 0.3, I get the two solutions -0.0132918... and 0.0132918...

Comment: Oh yes, let me edit to show how to fix that with save positions

Comment: Edited with `save_positions` so there's no extra save at the steps.

Comment: Is this still the recommended way of simulating a reflecting barrier in 2021? I noticed that it doesn't seem to work for SDE Solvers that use adaptive stepping

Comment: It should be fine. What's the issue?

Comment: I've made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049991/simulating-a-reflecting-boundary-sdeproblem